# CakePHP 3.x - How to delete records from multiple tables in a single transaction?

Tags: cakephp, orm, transactions, cakephp-3.x

How can I modify the code below to ensure that both deletes will be conducted in one transaction in CakePHP 3.x?

```
// In initialize:
$this->loadModel('A');

// In the delete function: 
$elem=$this->A->get($id);
$rec=$elem->...; 
$this->A->delete($elem);

$this->loadModel('B');
$this->B->deleteAll(['B.rec'=>$rec]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For associated tables

In case your tables are associated to each other, you could use the `dependent` option to define an association where dependent records are being deleted automatically. By default that will happen in a transaction.

```
 $this->hasMany('B', [
     'dependent' => true,
     // ...
 ]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Deleting Data > Cascading Deletes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html#cascading-deletes)**

### For non associated tables / non-dependent associations

That's what the `\Cake\Datasource\ConnectionInterface::transactional()` method, respectively the `\Cake\Database\Connection::begin()`, `commit()` and `rollback()` methods are there for.

Using `transactional()` is the easier approach, all operations done inside of the passed callback are being run in a transaction.

Quote from the docs:

> The transactional method will do the following:
>
> - Call `begin`.
> - Call the provided closure.
> - If the closure raises an exception, a rollback will be issued. The original exception will be re-thrown.
> - If the closure returns `false`, a rollback will be issued.
> - If the closure executes successfully, the transaction will be committed.

> **Returns**
>
> `mixed`
>   The return value of the callback.

So, wrap your code in a callback, and make sure to evaluate the `Table::delete()` return value and return `false` if necessary, so that a rollback is being issued in case the delete action fails.

```
$connection = \Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::get('default');
$result = $connection->transactional(function ($connection) use ($id) {
    $elem = $this->A->get($id);
    $rec = $elem->/*...*/;
    if (!$this->A->delete($elem, ['atomic' => false])) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->loadModel('B');
    $this->B->deleteAll(['B.rec' => $rec]);

    return true;
});
```

Note that the `atomic` option should be disabled in that case, so that `delete()` doesn't try to create a transaction itself.

It should also be noted that wrapping `delete()` calls inside transactions manually, will cause the `Model.afterDeleteCommit` event to *not* be fired, if your code needs that event to be fired, then you'd have to do that yourself.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Using Transactions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Connection::transactional()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.Connection.html#_transactional)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Deleting Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html#)**

Comment: After some time I have a small sub-question the topic: deleteAll() does not need 'atomic'=>false as it is in delete() function?

Comment: No it doesn't, `deleteAll()` issues a single delete query only and doesn't use transactions. @Annabelle

Comment: Thank you, I was not sure :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->Model->hasMany('TrModels', [ 'bindingKey' => 'transaction column', 'foreignKey' => 'transaction column', 'joinType' => 'LEFT', 'dependent' => true, 'cascadeCallbacks' => true,]);

          $deleteINQ = $this->Models->get($id);//Parrent id
         $this->Models->delete($deleteINQ);
```